# <select> tag style in IE - Apply the select tag style used by default in chrome

Tags: css, select, telerik

I`m new around here but a big consumer of this site over the years.
Were developing a SPA application using Durandal framework and are using Comboboxes which looks different accross browsers.

recently i have added the Telerik Kendo UI to the project and Kendo Comboboxes are great and cross browser supported as far as styling.

the problem is that we use complex knockout bindings that Telerik does not support and switch to Kendo will be a pain for these specific ctrls.

is there a way to apply the default Chrome  style to our project so it look the same across browsers(Safari, FF, Chrome & specially IE)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Going to have to add some code if you want some valid help. Unfortunately default inputs look different across all browsers, so the only way to make them look the same is to use a CSS reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and then style it how you want.

Comment: Ryan Niemeyer (a member of the Telerik team) maintains all of the Knockout bindings for Kendo UI.  Check out his link here: http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/.  Also, pay careful attention to this documentation note: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/KendoUI.html.  I asked Rob Eisenberg to add that note after wrestling with the issue for an hour.  The knockout-kendo bindings are very stable and extensible.

Comment: Thanks Guys! I also tried some 3-party`s like Bootstrap-select & chosen but got some strange behavior. will check out your links. Kendo-knockout works partialy, we have created a widget(custome Durandal widget) which works ok. Waiting to move to angular as Kendo supports it almost nativly